# No matching function call to T::T() in class template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to write a generic template class, but I keep getting this error when I try to implement it:

```
no matching function for call to type_impl::type_impl()
```

where type_impl is the type I'm trying to use the class with.

Here's my code:

```
class BaseClass {
protected:
    // Some data
public:
    BaseClass(){
        // Assign to data
    }; 
};

template <class T>
class HigherClass : BaseClass {
private:
    T data;
public:
    // Compiler error is here.
    HigherClass(){};
    // Other functions interacting with data
};

class Bar {
private:
    // Some data
public:
    Bar(/* Some arguments*/) {
        // Assign some arguments to data
    };
};

// Implementation
HigherClass<Bar> foo() {
     HigherClass<Bar> newFoo;

     // Do something to newFoo

     return newFoo;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, since you have provided a nondefault constructor for `Bar`, the compiler no longer provides a default constructor, and this is required in your code:

```
HigherClass(){}; // will init data using T()
```

So provide a default constructor for `Bar`. For example:

```
class Bar {

public:
    Bar() = default; // or code your own implementation
    Bar(/* Some arguments*/) { ... }
};
```

Comment: You may want to add why this is the case. eg. "When you try to create `HigherClass<Bar>` it has a member `Bar data` which needs a default contructor to be created."

Comment: @clcto Thanks, I was in the process of doing that. I hope it is clearer now.